# Grid becomes unresponsive when other page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid in a page with a couple of columns.I'm using KendoUI grid component to display the grid.  When a user clicks a link on the grid. It opens a new window and displays content. While this page is being processed for display and a user clicks on the grid in the first page, the grid becomes unresponsive. Is there any reason why it should behave that way ?

Here is some code which actually open the window on the click

```
$('#fileGrid,#searchResultsGrid').on('click', ".ceOutput", function (e) {
        $(this).target = "_blank"
        if ($(this).attr("disabled") != "disabled") {
            var dataItem = ceFeature.getCurrentdataItem(e)

            dataItem.xmi = ''
            dataItem.html = ''
            $.cookie("currentDocID", JSON.stringify(dataItem))
            window.open('file/content', '_blank', 'height=1000,width=1000,toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0')
            return false
        } else {
            return false
        }
    })
```

Comment: Please update your question to include details such as what grid component you are using, so that we're more able to understand and help. :)

Comment: I'm using Kendo UI Grid. I have also updated the question

Comment: Please post some code.